# Solving a sparse vector $x$ from system $Ax=b$ at the fastest possible way?

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

I'm going to solve this linear system:

$$Ax=b$$

Where $x$ is sparse. To do that, Inned to minimize this. This is called lasso regression.

$$\nabla J = ||Ax - b||_2 + \lambda ||x||_1$$

Where $\lambda > 0$. Notise that both $A$ and $b$ contains unsigned integer numbers of 8-bit, e.g `0...255`.

To solve that $x$ we can use `Sequential Threshold Least Squares`.

```
function x = stls_regression(A, b, lambda)
  x = linsolve2(A, b);
  state_dimension = size(b, 2);
  for k=1:10
      smallinds = (abs(x)<lambda);     
      x(smallinds) = 0;                 
      for ind = 1:state_dimension         
        biginds = ~smallinds(:,ind);
        x(biginds,ind) = linsolve2(A(:,biginds),b(:,ind));
      end
  end
end

function x = linsolve2(A, b)
  % Solve upper triangular
  [A, b] = backsubstitution(A'*A, A'*b);
  x = solveUp(A, b);
  
  % Gauss
  %x = gauss_jordan(A'*A, A'*b);
  
  % Least squares
  %x = inv(A'*A)*A'*b; 
  
  % LUP factorization
  [L, U, P] = lu(A'*A);
  y = L\(P*A'*b);
  %x = U\y;
  
  % QR factorization
  [Q,R] = qr2(A);
    %x = linsolve(R, Q'*b);
  
  % Pseudo inverse
  [U, S, V] = svd(A, 'econ');
  %x = V*inv(S)*U'*b;
end

function [y] = gauss_jordan (K, L)
      x = [K L];
    for n = 1:(length(x)-1)
        % Step 1: make the row N's Nth term 1 by dividing 
        % the whole row by it
        A = x(n,:);
        A = A/A(n);
        x(n,:) = A;
        
        % Step 2: for every other row add to it -1 * that rows Nth term *
        % the Nth row
        for k = 1:(length(x)-1)
            if n~=k
                x(k,:) = A*(-1*x(k,n)) + x(k,:);
            end
        end
    end
    
    y = x(:,length(x));
end

function [x] = solveUp(A, b)
      s = length(A);
      x = zeros(s,1);
      x(s) = b(s)/A(s,s);
      for i = s-1:-1:1
          sum = 0;
          for j = s:-1:i+1
              sum = sum + A(i,j)*x(j);
          end
          x(i) = (b(i)- sum)/A(i,i);
      end
    end

function [A, b] = backsubstitution(A, b)
      s = length(A);
      for j = 1:(s-1)
          for i = s:-1:j+1
              m = A(i,j)/A(j,j);
              A(i,:) = A(i,:) - m*A(j,:);
              b(i) = b(i) - m*b(j);
          end
      end
    end

function [Q,R] = qr2(A)
      % Compute the QR decomposition of an m-by-n matrix A using% Householder transformations.
      [m,n] = size(A);
      Q = eye(m);      % Orthogonal transform so farR = A;
      R = A;           % Transformed matrix so far
      % This make sure that we can use A transpose as well
      if(m <= n)
        n = m;
      end
      for j = 1:n % -- Find H = I-tau*w*w’ to put zeros below R(j,j)
        normx = norm(R(j:end,j));
        s     = -sign(R(j,j));
        u1    = R(j,j) - s*normx;
        w     = R(j:end,j)/u1;
        w(1)  = 1;
        tau   = -s*u1/normx;
        % Find Q and R now
        R(j:end,:) = R(j:end,:)-(tau*w)*(w'*R(j:end,:));
        Q(:,j:end) = Q(:,j:end)-(Q(:,j:end)*w)*(tau*w)';
      end
    end
```

For example, if you try to run this code.

```
  lambda = 0.15;
  A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; 4 1 5 6 2 2 5 6 2 10; 3 5 6 1 6 8 4 2 9 5; 2 4 5 6 2 1 7 9 6 4];
  b = 1:4;
  b = b';
  x1 = linsolve(A, b)
  x2 = stls_regression(A, b, lambda)
  b1 = A*x1
  b2 = A*x2
```

You will get different $x_1 \neq x_2$, due to $x_2$ is sparse.
But $Ax_1 = Ax_2$

**Question:**

The function `linsolve` in MATLAB uses LUP-factorization if $A$ is square and QR-factorization if matrix $A$ is non-square. Those are very computationally expensive. But in this case, $A$ will be transformed to square $A^* = A'A$ and $b^* = A'b$ before I run `Sequential Threshold Least Squares`. The goal is to solve $A'Ax = A'b$.

What is the **fastest way** then for me to solve

$$\nabla J = ||A^*x - b^*||_2$$

If I only care about $x$ being sparse and precision is not so important for me? I have tried out

1. Backsubstitution - Excellent
2. Gauss-Jordan - Excellent, just inscrease lambda to 0.28
3. Least squares - Did not work at all.
4. LUP factorization - Excellent
5. QR factorization - Excellent
6. Pseudo inverse - Excellent

Is backsubsitution the best algorithm in this case?

Comment: Fastest $\implies$ $QR$. Most stable $\implies$ SVD

Comment: @xXACEXx Thank you for your reply! I know that SVD is the best choice for stability. But never heard that QR should be fastest. Why not gaussian eleminiation?

Comment: I have updated my answer, it seems that I did not notice that you included the $LU$ decomposition, indeed it is faster than $QR$ and would seem most feasible.

Comment: @xXACEXx Notice that I'm doing this in C code only. QR may look easy in MATLAB code, but QR in C code looks like this: https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/master/src/CControl/Sources/LinearAlgebra/qr.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of the $QR$ decomposition of your matrix $A$ will transform the least square problem as follow :
\begin{aligned}
\|b-A x\|_{2} &=\min _{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}\|b-A y\|_{2} \\
\|b-Q R x\|_{2} &=\min _{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}\|b-Q R y\|_{2} \\
\left\|Q^{T}(b-Q R x)\right\|_{2} &=\min _{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}\left\|Q^{T}(b-Q R y)\right\|_{2} \\
\left\|Q^{T} b-R x\right\|_{2} &=\min _{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}\left\|Q^{T} b-R y\right\|_{2} \\
\|c-R x\|_{2} &=\min _{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}\|c-R y\|_{2} \quad \text { where } c=Q^{T} b
\end{aligned}

Assuming $m\geq n$, you can use MATLAB's built-in function $\mathsf{qr}$ and $\mathsf{svd}$ for a matrix $\mathsf{B=rand}(100)$ and $\mathsf{b=rand(100,1)}$ where $\mathsf{A=B+B'}$. You can use MATLAB's built-in function $\mathsf{timeit}$ to measure the run time of each version on $\|b-Ax\|_{2}$ and you'll conclude that $QR$ factorization is most reliable in terms of speed instead of $SVD$.

---

It is worth noting that the $LU$ decomposition accounts for $mn^{2}-n^{3}/3$ flops assuming $m\geq n$, this is about half as $QR$ decomposition which accounts for $2mn^{2}-2n^{3}/3$.

The choice of algorithm implemented in MATLAB is essentially based on how much structure your matrix has that can be exploited to achieve better performance. Sometimes you might not have a desirable symmetric matrix and thus if you use $LU$ your computation might be slow. However, it is faster than $QR$ since the $LU$ would account for $\frac{2}{3}m^{3}$ flops unlike $QR$ which would account for $\frac{4}{3}m^{3}$ flops.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I don't think QR is the fastest.

Comment: I think gauss-jordan is the fastest algorithm.